# A pattern to destructively extract items from an array

Tags: ruby, array

I want to efficiently (few intermediate objects) and neatly (few lines and easy to read) filter an array, removing *and returning* rejected items. So like a call to delete_if except instead of returning the remaining items, returning the deleted items.

Here's some code that works:

```
ary = (0..9).to_a
odds = ary.select {|i| i%2==1 }
ary -= odds
```

or:

```
ary = (0..9).to_a
(_,ary),(_,odds) = ary.group_by {|i| i.odd? }.sort {|a,b| a[0] ? 1 : -1 }
```

But I can't help but think there should be a better way...

Ideally something more like: `odds = ary.delete_and_return(&:odd?)`

Comment: `deleted = ary - ary.select(&:someproc)` seems totally fine to me

Answer (score 4):

`Array.partition` returns an array of two arrays - one where the elements returned `true` to the condition, and one that returned `false`.

So, a single liner for your need would be:

```
odds, ary = (0..9).to_a.partition(&:odd?)
=> [[1, 3, 5, 7, 9], [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]]
```

`(&:odd?)` acts exactly like writing `{ |x| x.odd? }` which will return true if the number is, well, odd...

Answer (score 2):

it is [built-in](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_if) :

```
ary.delete_if( &:odd? )
```

**EDIT**

Sorry, misread your question. You can do this :

```
deleted = ary.select( &:odd? ).tap{|odd| ary -= odd }
```

Comment: as a side note, it is sad that `Enumerable#drop` does not provide this functionality : it would accept a block, drop _n or all_ elements where the block returns true, and return the dropped elements. I wish I knew C better to patch it...

Answer (score 1):

You need [`#partition`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition):

```
irb> a = (1..9).to_a
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
irb> a.partition(&:odd?).tap{ |y, n| a = n }.first
=> [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
irb> a
=> [2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Comment: Can you please explain your answer?

Comment: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no such method yet in ruby, you can always add your own if that makes sense to your use case (if you find yourself needing that method a lot).

Here is and example implementation:

```
class Array
  def extract! &block
    extracted = select(&block)
    reject!(&block)
    extracted
  end
end
```

The code above first selects what you want to return and then destructively removes those items which is what you want to avoid doing manually to improve readability.

Note: the method is called `extract!` with a bang since it modifies the array itself. If the method wuould not modify the underlying object, it would be equivalent to `select`, so you might name it `select!`, or `select_and_remove!` if you prefer.

Usage:

```
a = (0..10).to_a

# extract even numbers from our array
p a.extract!(&:even?) # => [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]

# odd numbers are left
p a # => [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```